# Case sensitive LIKE and WHERE clause matching in MySQL using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, case-sensitive, case-insensitive

My database/table/column collation is set to *_ci mean case insensitive. What I want is to write case sensitive query on run time using CodeIgniter for LIKE and WHERE clause. I tried an approach something like this

```
$this->db->where("fieldname LIKE BINARY 'value'", NULL, true);
```

But this approach is not working with LIKE clause

```
$this->db->like("fieldname LIKE BINARY 'value'", NULL);
```

Any type of help will greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why don't you simply use where clause like as `$this->db->where("fieldname","value");
`

Comment: Because my database/table/column collation is set to *_ci so using simple query will follow parent collation and this is not I want!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well well well ...

After searching around and hammering my head I finally solved this issue! First of all I have to set the collation of table/column to *_cs, after that if I need case sensitive matching I have to run simple

```
$this->db->where('field', 'value');
```

or

```
$this->db->like('field', 'value');
```

But if you want case insensitive matching than use

```
$this->db->where("LOWER('field')", strtolower('value'), false);
```

> $this->db->where() accepts an optional third parameter. If you set it to FALSE, CodeIgniter will not try to protect your field or table names with backticks.

or

```
$this->db->like("LOWER('field')", strtolower('value'));
```

> Remember CodeIgniter follows the standard collation of your MySQL database, there is no built in function is available in CI 2.x to over write default database collation. So if your column/table collation is set to *_ci (case insensitive) CI will consider abc = aBc but if your collation is set as *_cs it will consider abc != aBc

Answer (score 2):

How about this

```
$value = "abdulla";
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE fieldname1 Like '%$value%' OR fieldname2 Like '%$value%'");
$result = $query->result_array();
```

actually `$this->db->like();` act as  `WHERE ??? LIKE '???'`

***For example***

```
$this->db->like('name', 'abdulla');     
// Produces: WHERE name LIKE '%abdulla%'
```

Comment: What this $ is presented for @Abdulla

Comment: Why you used $ sign in %$value%

Comment: its because `$value` is variable. You can see top of the function

Comment: @Adnan did you check this??

Comment: Yes @Abdulla but it is not working for me, I finally found solution for this issue :)

Comment: @Adnan you can improve my post with your ideas.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `get()` method like:

```
$result = $this->db
    ->where('fieldname like binary "value"', NULL, FALSE)
    ->get('table')
    ->result();
```

Comment: I already mentioned this procedure but this is not working with LIKE, how I will make it work with LIKE clause!

Answer (score 1):

So you can try it like as

```
$this->db->like('fieldname', 'value');
```

You can control the wildcard `(%)` as per your needs you can use `'before'`, `'after'` and `'both'`. If you don't need the wildcard then you can simply pass the third parameter as `none`.

Check the [**DOCS**](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)